# LoginAsync using Access Token and MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I'm getting a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." error when I try to `LoginAsync` with an access token and `MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory`. This works with the equivalent form with `MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount`. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Is there a configuration I'm missing?

```
var msaProvider = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync(
"https://login.microsoft.com",
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3dd13bb9-5d0d-dd2e-9d1e-7a966131bf85");
string clientId = "6d15468d-9dbe-4270-8d06-a540dab3252f";
WebTokenRequest request1 = new WebTokenRequest(msaProvider, "User.Read", clientId);
request1.Properties.Add("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
WebTokenRequestResult result =
await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(request1);
    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        var token = result.ResponseData[0].Token;
        var token1 = new JObject
                {
                    { "access_token", token }
                };
        var user = await App.mobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(
            MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, token1);
```

Comment: If you want to authenticate user with ADAL, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#adal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get MSAL.NET to work for this per code below. The key is the `{ resourceId + "/user_impersonation" }` scope.

```
PublicClientApplication pca = new PublicClientApplication(clientId)
                    {
                        RedirectUri = redirectUri
                    };
                    string[] scopes = { resourceId + "/user_impersonation" };
                    var users = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
                    var user = users.FirstOrDefault();
                    AuthenticationResult msalar = await pca.AcquireTokenAsync(
                        scopes, user, UIBehavior.ForceLogin, "domain_hint=test.net");
                         payload = new JObject
                         {
                             ["access_token"] = msalar.AccessToken
                         };
 mobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

Reference: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/660#issuecomment-433831737